# get dynamic_sidebar() value in array in wordpress

Tags: sidebar, array

I have a sidebar. Till now I am calling this as

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'home-left-widget-area' );
```

and this shows data in `<li>`. But I need data in `<option>` .

How to store values in array so I can use `<option>`

Comment: I do not understand why you would insert widgets into `<option>` tags. Are you trying to put the whole widget into a `<select>` menu? What are you trying to do?

Comment: yes I am working on responsive theme so I need all the sidebar values in <select> . So I need all values in array as we get of menus

Comment: I am 99% sure that is going to result in very broken markup. I would suggest you rethink your approach.

Comment: can you tell me how to store values in array when I use dynamic_sidebar()

Comment: the html markup of the sidebar is set in the `register_sidebar()` codes usually in functions.php of the theme. alternatively possibly consider to program as a custom widget, whatever you want to create.

Answer (score 1):

Widgets `echo` data. Take a look at the `widget` method of some of the default widgets, [like this one](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L21).

You can't save that data to an array without writing your own function to process the widgets and using output buffering where the widgets themselves `echo` content. And sidebars/sidebar-widgets are complicated. That is not an easy function to write.

Sidebars are not meant to do what you want to do and even if you got it working your markup would be broken since you would be shoving whole widgets into a `<select>`. You'd have all kinds of things inside the `<select>` menu that are not supposed to be there. Try pushing something like this through the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check):

```
<select>
  <option>
   <div><p><em>Hi</em></p></div>
   <li>
     hello
   </li>
  </option>
</select>
```

That is something like what you will get.

What you are trying to do is complicated and *wrong* and browsers may not parse the markup correctly enough to do what you expect it to do anyway. I'd bet they would not. Complicated chunks of block level content are not supposed to be inside a select menu.

You do not need markup in a select menu to have a responsive theme. You need to rethink what you are doing.